# list index out of range error received

Tags: python, debugging, list

hey guys, beginner here. I have written a program that outputs files to .txt's and am using another to read them and use them. i have used a list to store these values (len(..) gives me 100 for all files). However, whenever i run this:

```
for w in range(1,20): # i want files file01-file20 excluding file00
    for x in range(100):
        c=c+1 #counter to keep list position on f=0
        exec "f=open('file%02d.txt','r').readlines()"%w #stores data from file00,file01,file02...
        f00=open('file00.txt','r').readlines() #same as ^ but from file00
        for y in range(100):
            xvp=float(f[c].rstrip('\n')) #the error is on this line; the file are stored in vertical order
            pvp=float(f00[y].rstrip('\n')) #maybe even this one
            #and i do stuff with those values...
```

I get in line 12,
    xvp=float(f[c].rstrip('\n'))
    IndexError: list index out of range

note: there are 100 numbers stored on separate lines in the .txt's

please, if there is any way to help you help me, let me know
thanks

Comment: Where are the variables c and r defined? What is 'r'?

Comment: sorry, c is defined c=-1 right before the first loop is called. the 'r' denotes that it is opening the file in read mode. It is the default mode, but its habit :P

Comment: It's not an answer, but why are you using `exec`?

Comment: It looks like you're unnecessarily iterating over the `xvp=float(f[c]...)` an extra 100 times for every x in the range. Why not move that out of the `for y in range(100)` block? Have you tried to `print` the contents of `f` and `f00` just to be sure you're grabbing what you think you are? Lastly, it doesn't seem that you're closing your files because you don't ever store the file handles. This is a leak.

Comment: Okay, I'm new to Python as well, but I'll take a shot.

What happens if you run the code without the loop? Like just try file00 at first and try 
' xvp=float(f[0].rstrip('\n'))'

Comment: ok, yes xvp=float(f[0].rstrip('\n')) runs with no error

Comment: why use exec when you can use formatting just in file name like 

"f = fopen('file%02d.txt'%w, 'r' ).readlines"

Comment: @cji: haha cuz it works, i know its bad style but i just need to finish this
@shamster: @extra iterations: yes, i did not notice that ty. @everything else: yes, printing them shows the correct data;what are file handles? plz excuse me for noobness

Comment: @pjehyun: when you call `open(...)` the function returns a file handle to the file. Good python (good programmers) will store file handles and ensure that they are all closed before termination. If you don't close the files then various bad things can happen. Thus, typical programs will 1. store the file handle `f=open(...)`, 2. do something `data=f.readlines()`, and 3. close the file `f.close()`.

Comment: Take xvp=float(f[c].rstrip('\n')) out of the loop. I don't see why you need to access it 100 times with the same value (c won't change in that loop, only y will)

Comment: @shamster: ok, i see what you are saying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be incrementing `c` two thousand times (20 times 100 -- actually only 1900 times, since `range(1,20)` will **not** reach the value 20, as you seem to desire in a comment) -- so of course you're going out of range if you use it to index a list of 100!  The whole code is rather a mess and I suggest refactoring it radically, to avoid `exec` and do things the Python way.  Assuming Python 2.6 or better (in 2.5, you need a `from __future__ import with_statement` at the start of your module):

```
f00 = open('file00.txt').readlines()
for w in range(1, 21):
    for x in range(100):
        with open('file%02d.txt' % w) as f:
            for line in f:
                xvp = float(line)
                for line00 in f00:
                    rvp = float(line00)
                    do_stuff(xvp, rvp)
```

I don't know if this is the logic you want -- coupling every line of `file00.txt` with *each* line from the 20 other files -- but at least this makes it *clear* which lines are coupled up with which;-).  If what you want is to only couple the *first* line of `file00.txt` with the first line from each of the others, then second line with second lines, etc, then add `import itertools` at the start of your module and change the contents of the `with` into:

```
            for line00, line in itertools.izip(f00, f):
                rvp = float(line00)
                xvp = float(line)
                do_stuff(xvp, rvp)
```

and so forth.

Note that I'm reading all of `file00.txt` in memory once and for all (into the `f00` list of lines) because apparently you need to loop on those contents more than once, but that's not needed for the other files.

An obvious optimization is to convert `file00.txt`'s lines to floats only once, replacing the `f00 =` statement with

```
with open('file00.txt') as f:
  rvps = [float(line) for line in f]
```

then use `rvps` directly instead of repeating the conversion every time on the strings in `f00` -- for example, in the second version (the one using `itertools.izip`):

```
            for rvp, line in itertools.izip(rvps, f):
                xvp = float(line)
                do_stuff(xvp, rvp)
```

**Edit**: I see I've done a number of tiny enhancements while hardly realizing I was doing so, maybe I'd better explain them;-).  No need to pass `'r'` when opening a file for reading (can't hurt, but it's quite idiomatic to omit it).  No need to strip trailing (or for that matter leading) whitespace from a string before calling `float` on it -- `float` happily skips all such leading and trailing whitespace itself.  I did fix what apparently was another bug (you'd never deal with `file20.txt`) by fixing the applicable `range` to `range(1, 21)`.

The `with open(...) as f:` statements do the opening, bind name `f` to the open file object, and, as soon as the block of statements they control is finished, guarantee that the file is properly closed -- it should almost invariably be used in preference to a stand-alone `open`, because ensuring all files are closed ASAP is really very good practice (the `with` statement has many other excellent use cases, but this is the single most frequent one, and the only one that happens to be necessary for this functionality).

Looping directly on an open file object `f` (provided the file is opened in text mode, as is the default and applies throughout here), `for line in f:`, provides one after the other the lines of `f` (without ever needing to keep them all in memory at once) and is an extremely popular and good Pythonic idiom.

The construct `rvps = [float(line) for line in f]`, which I use in my recommended optimization, is known as a "list comprehension" and it's a nicely speedy and compact alternative to a loop that builds a new list.

`itertools.izip`, given a number of iterables, provides a single iterable whose items are tuples made by the items of the other iterables "walked in lockstep".  The built-in `zip` is similar, but (in Python 2) it builds a list in memory, which `itertools.izip` avoids, so it's good practice to learn to use the `itertools` version to avoid wasting memory (not really important for small files like the ones you have, but good habits are best learned and "just applied" rather than having to reflect on them every single time -- just one one doesn't start every morning pondering whether one should brush one's teeth, but just goes and does so as a matter of good habit;-).

I'm sure there's more, but this is what comes to mind off-hand - feel free to ask if I can be of further assistance!

Comment: I am unworthy, thank you so much i wish i could give more up arrows :). just one question, what is rvps? is it a type of pvp or is it actual syntax

Comment: @piehyun, you're welcome -- you can't give more up arrows, but you _can_ give the acceptance checkmark, if and when you choose, by clicking the now-empty outline thereof at the left of my answer;-). Re your question: I just arbitrarily named `rvps` the list whose items I will each name `rvp` later -- I have no idea what `rvp` stands for, so it's hard to think of a better name;-).  Using `xs` to name "the list whose item I'll call `x`" is a not-very-Pythonic habit I think I picked up from some functional programming language or other, where it's quite widespread (and catchy in its conciseness)

Answer (score 1):

> there are 100 numbers stored on
>   separate lines in the .txt's

but in

```
for w in range(1,20): # i want files file01-file20 excluding file00
    for x in range(100):
        c=c+1 #counter to keep list position on f=0
```

you incrementing c by 20*100 = 2000 times.

Maybe you need c = 0 in "w" cycle or just use x instead of c?

Answer (score 1):

Based on how you describe your files, you are indexing into them incorrectly.  By using `c` which is incremented for each iteration of the second loop.  It will reach values of up to 2000.  Using `x` seems to be the logical choice.

```
#restructured for efficiency
file = open('file00.txt','r')
f00 = file.readlines() #no need to reopen the file for every iteration
file.close() #always close the file when done with
for w in range(1,20):
    file = open('file%02d.txt'%w,'r')
    f = file.readlines() #only open once per iteration
    file.close()
    for x in range(100):
        xvp = float(f[x].rstrip('\n'))
        for y in range(100):
            pvp = float(f00[y].rstrip('\n'))
            #do stuff
```

Comment: 1900, actually -- the comment is misinformation, `range(1, 20)` of course does *not* go all the way up to 20, but only to 19 (presumably, given the comment, that's yet one more bug in the OP's code).

Comment: @Alex: Ah right, missed that.  But still ridiculously large.  ;)

Comment: yep, 1900 is definitely too much too;-).